Ejecutar y obtener el simbolo del codigo ASCII en Java
¿Como ejecutar los codigos ASCII en java desde visual studio code ?, porque cuando lo hago me sale solo un signo de interrogacion "?" ?
Intente ejecutar este codigo:
public class Unicode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char letra1 = '\u00ae'; 
        System.out.println(letra1);
    }
}

salio:
�

El código está bien. El problema es de tu terminal.
Asegúrate de que la tipografía que usa para mostrar el texto tenga un símbolo para ese caracter. Deberías poder cambiar la tipografía desde la configuración de Visual Studio Code.
Si estás usando conhost (la interfaz de terminal por defecto de Windows) puedes hacerlo dando clic derecho al título y yendo a Propiedades.
Si estás usando la nueva terminal de Windows, encontrarás la opción en un apartado de la configuración.
Por cierto, la codificación ASCII solo está definida hasta el valor 127. Lo que estás usando es la codificación Unicode, por lo tanto deberías ver el símbolo ®.
